# Morph multiple gateways into warp gates simultaneously

Tags: starcraft-2

I've seen a number of higher-level players select a number of gateways and morph them all simultaneously into warp gates. How do you do that? If I press the "G" button, it just starts one of them warping. Can they be set to all morph simultaneously, or are my eyes just playing tricks on me?

Comment: How fast can you press your "G" button? I'm nearly positive they're simply hitting the hotkey as many times as they have gateways.

Comment: Not fast enough, apparently :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to do them all automatically. You just repeatedly press <kbd>G</kbd> *really fast*, or hold it down and let the keyboard auto repeat. (I'm assuming most pro StarCraft II players have a fairly low key repeat delay.)

Comment: I'm pressing just G and wait while all icons at the bottoms changed

Comment: I just click the button rapidly. Unless I'm playing on "Fastest map ever" and have 15 gateways or so, they always transform about instantaneously. In regular games its more of an issue to find and select them if I have 2 at the wall and 2 in my base. I usually add production buildings to a hotkey when I build them. (Of course, once they are transformed, you can use the 'W' key.)