# Chronoboost all gateways simultaneously

Tags: starcraft-2

Similar [to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17703/morph-multiple-gateways-into-warp-gates-simultaneously?rq=1), I have seen in a lot of pro-replays players seemingly chronoboosing all 8 of their warp gates simultaneously.

Usually when I do it, I hot-key nexus, hot-key chronoboost, click gateway. But the in the replays, it seems as if it is done simultaneously because the chronoboost animations are synced on a large amount of gateways.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do it simultaneously, but you can get pretty close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you hold down the Shift Key with your Nexus selected (or nexuses), press C and continue to hold down the shift key and then click on each gateway. It's not simultaneous, but it is as fast as you can click, move, and click again. It does remove the requirement to keep hitting C to chronoboost each gateway though.

It appears to be simultaneous because the pros do it so fast.

Comment: Progamers have mad mouse skill. Try to search for videos where you can actually see them sitting at the computer, you'll be amazed.

Comment: How did you get Programmers out of SCII?

Comment: Ohhhh Pro-Gamers... Jesus those two names look alike!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the shift-click mechanic, being able to chrono-boost buildings via the minimap would contribute greatly to bringing about a simultaneous chrono across all of your gateways. It requires a bit of practice to get used to accurately clicking on buildings from the minimap (especailly in tense situations), but learning this skill will speed up your macro considerably.

Comment: Are you suggesting to chrono the buildings by shift clicking the small dots on the minimap? This is nearly impossible for huge maps, especially if you cluster all your buildings. Then you just have a huge (green) blob.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was referring to. It is more difficult on a 4v4 map, but not impossible. My Zerg and Protoss games are much easier now that I have that skill down, macro is a lot less scary because of it.